# Conditions for a system to be solvable.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, linear-programming

I have the following system of equations:
$$\begin{aligned} \left\{\begin{array}{l}
 a+dz+cy+exy = 0\\ 
 10a+3bx-exy =0\\ 
-5a-dz = 0 
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned}~~.$$

I would like to solve for $x,y$ and $z$. In order to do that I realize conditions have to placed on the constant coefficients $a, b, c, d $ and $e$ and that in a nutshell is the question I'm asking. i.e. What conditions do the the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ need to satisfy in order for the above system to have a solution/solutions.

At the moment all I'm able to come up with is the following: If $d\neq 0$, then $z=\frac{5a}{d}$. I've also thought of assuming that $xy=0$ but that only gives trivial solutions. What if $xy\neq 0$?

PS: I am not sure about which tags are appropriate, so please feel free to edit accordingly.

Comment: This isn't a linear system because we have $xy$ term in the system. You'll need to know about Groebner bases to solve it

Comment: ok. How do I use Groebner bases to solve it.

Comment: It's not that easy. You can read about it in any book that is about computational algebraic geometry. One good book for that is Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'shea.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use Groebner bases. The system is not linear but you have the same nonlinear term in two of the equations so you can still handle this with your typical algebra and matrix skills.

First you find $z = -5a/d$.

Your next step would be to add equations 1 and 2, thus eliminating the nonlinear term $e \cdot x \cdot y$.

You get $ 11 \cdot a + d \cdot z + 3 \cdot b \cdot x + c \cdot y =0$.

Solve this equation for y in terms of x.

Then you can plug y into either equations 1 or 2, whichever you prefer and you will end up with 
$$ x = (-3 \cdot b \cdot c - 6 \cdot a \cdot e \pm \sqrt {-120 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot e + (3 \cdot b \cdot c + 6 \cdot a \cdot e)^2})/(6 \cdot b \cdot e) $$

Plugging z and x into one of the top two equations yields y:

$$ y = (3 \cdot b \cdot c - 6 \cdot a \cdot e \pm \sqrt {-120 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot e + (3 \cdot b \cdot c + 6 \cdot a \cdot e)^2})/(2 \cdot c \cdot e) $$